# How to delete KeyValue in Visual studio 2012 c++ richTextBox

Tags: c++-cli, richtextbox

How i can delete the key which presente "Enter"?? I want the programme show "Plase enter Espace or Tab" when the user tape Enter and then delete this Enter Key. Thank you!

```
private: System::Void richTextBoxCommentaire_KeyDown(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventArgs^  e) {
             if (e->KeyValue == (char)13)
             {
                    MessageBox::Show ("Please enter Espace or Tab");
//To delete this Key??
                 }
             }
```

Comment: Cleaned up tags: C++/CLI != C++, and this is not about Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, using the previewKeyDown should have worked but try the next method :

Use the KeyDown event to filter the desired keys by setting the `suppressKeyPress` to `true` as you can see in the example below (the example is in C# for readability but conversion to C++ CLI should be trivial :) :

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.SuppressKeyPress = e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter;
}
```

Comment: i have done this   
private: System::Void richTextBoxCommentaire_PreviewKeyDown(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::PreviewKeyDownEventArgs^  e) {
   if (e->KeyValue == (char)13)
    {
     e->IsInputKey = false;
     MessageBox::Show("Veuillez saisir Tab ou Espace");
}  

}

but the Enter Key is always in my richTextBox ... Why???